# Is there a fixed ratio between highest L/D and max endurance L/D?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, flight-mechanics

It can be demonstrated that, for any airplane, there is a fixed ratio between the maximum range and maximum endurance speeds (1.31607...).
Does another, fixed ratio exist between highest L/D and L/D at maximum endurance speed...?

Comment: "It's known that,"  from where?

Comment: @CrossRoads  Changed to 'it can be demonstrated...' https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/36443/16042

Comment: Cool, I hadn't seen that formula before. Can find out some neat stuff just by asking where an assumption came from.